# How to make click event work for toggleClass with stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a dropdown component. I want to:

1. show dropdown on button click,
2. hide dropdown on second click on the same button,
3. hide dropdown on click outside of it,
4. do not hide dropdown when click inside of it,
5. only one dropdown can be visible at once.

I have the following code:

```
$('.js-dropdown-toggler').click(function(e){
  $('.js-dropdown').removeClass('is-open');
  $(this).next('.js-dropdown').toggleClass('is-open');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function(){
  if ($('.js-dropdown').hasClass('is-open')) {
    $('.js-dropdown').removeClass('is-open');
  }
});

$('.js-dropdown').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

It doesn't hide the dropdown on the second click on the same button. If to remove `$('.js-dropdown').removeClass('is-open');` then dropdowns remain when click on the another button.

I guess the problem is with using click event for toggleClass with stopPropagation.

I'll appreciate any help.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/ierhyna/pen/wMyWZG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your current code as shown below:

```
$('.js-dropdown-toggler').click(function(e){
  var current = $(this).next('.js-dropdown');
  current.toggleClass('is-open');
  $('.js-dropdown').not(current).removeClass('is-open');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('html').click(function(){
  if ($('.js-dropdown').hasClass('is-open')) {
    $('.js-dropdown').removeClass('is-open');
  }
});
```

The point is that your dropdowns should be "mutually exclusive": when one is showing up - the other goes to hide simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line in your handler for `'.js-dropdown-toggler'`:

`$('.js-dropdown').removeClass('is-open');`

Comment: then dropdowns remain when click on the another button.

Comment: Apologies, I was only paying attention to the toggling of the dropdown, forgot about only one being open at a time.